# (Java)When store contents from text file into an array, output of printing array was all null

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, null, filereader

I am new to Java, recently has an assignment which involve array. It's just the first part of it, and I am trying to store the content from a file into an array, but the outcome was [null,null,null......]. I had tried using these
 `String[] array = list.toArray(new String[count]);`
`List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` 
but it does not work, searching through stackoverflow and found similar example as above and as below method of storing content in array but still, hope you could give me some light on what is really happening and so I could debug this. Thank you.

The example of content:

```
3
123
456 
789
```

I need to save it as string as it is a really long number in the assignment

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Array {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FileReader theFile = new FileReader("path of the file");
            BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(theFile);

            String content;
            String lineInFile = readFile.readLine();
            int count = 0; 
            while(lineInFile != null)
            {
                count++;
                lineInFile = readFile.readLine();
            }

            System.out.println(count);
            String[] array = new String[count];
            for(int o = 0; o < count; o++)
            {
                content = lineInFile + "";
                lineInFile = readFile.readLine();
                array[o] = lineInFile;
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling **Readline** and rewriting the object lineInFile over and over again...

Here:

```
String lineInFile = readFile.readLine();
int count = 0; 
while(lineInFile != null)
{
    count++;
    lineInFile = readFile.readLine();
}
```

you should put this  inside the while

```
 array[o] = lineInFile;
```

and instead of **o** use **count** variable

Comment: To clarify this a little bit, the while loop is looping until readFile reaches the end of the file (when readline() returns null). Then in the second loop, since readFile is already at the end of the file, readline() will only return null, hence the array full of nulls. To do what chloe.t intended would require a new BufferedReader before the second loop, but ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ's solution is better.

Comment: I tried to run this, but it gives me this error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 which appeared a lot of times during debugging. Thanks for your fast response!                      int count = 0; 
 String[] array = new String[count];
 while(lineInFile != null)
 {
  content = lineInFile + "";
  array[count] = content;
  count++;

 }

Comment: @marks I think you need to know buffer size in order to initialize the array. This is the purpose of the first while loop. I think you cannot assign any buffer line to array before initialize it with size specified by `count` variable. Otherwise you obtain an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as @chloe.t reported.

Comment: @chloe.t Paolo is correct, so if you must use an array (instead of a List, or even better a StringBuffer since you're ending with a String) you will need to call readFile.close() and then readFile = new BufferedReader(theFile); to recreate the StringBuffer at the beginning.

Comment: @marks thanks for your explanations! it works for me now!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the first part of your code read all the line in the file in order to init `count` variable :

```
String lineInFile = readFile.readLine();
int count = 0; 
while(lineInFile != null)
{
    count++;
    lineInFile = readFile.readLine();
}
```

... and give size to the array

```
String[] array = new String[count];
```

Now you need to reset file buffer before load file content into array, therefore you need to insert this line:

```
readFile.reset();
```

before this:

```
for(int o = 0; o < count; o++)
        {
            content = lineInFile + "";
            lineInFile = readFile.readLine();
            array[o] = lineInFile;
        }
```

`content` variable declaration and initialization seems useless you can delete

Edit: As @marks suggest you need to insert following before reset method:
    readFile.mark(0);
    readFile.reset();

Comment: This will work, but you'll need to call readFile.mark() before reading the first line or you will get an [IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#reset%28%29) on the readFile.reset()

Answer (score 0):

You can get all lines from the `readFile` by using the `lines()`-method

```
String[] array = readFile.lines().toArray()
```

So you don't need to count and read by yourself.

You can also use the `Files`-class

```
String[] array = (String[])Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path to file")).toArray();
```